# Password Hash Implementation

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I am developing a new application using Symfony. I want to store the passwords hashed, so I overridded the save method in my User model:

```
public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
{
    $this->setUserPassword( md5($this->getUserPassword()) );
return parent::save($conn);
}
```

This works good when a new user created. However, this causes problems when we edit a user without changing his password. This causes Doctrine to hash the already hashed password.

So, I need to check that whether the UserPassword is modified in this DoctrineRecord instance. How can I manage to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution:
We need to override the setter method only:

```
public function setUserPassword($password)
{
    return $this->_set('user_password', md5($password));
}
```

Comment: Damn, 3rd question I look where the OP answered himself before anyone. I guess SO's gonna die soon, people became too smart !